# SOLR exact search turn off stemming

Tags: solr, solr4

I am using SOLR 4.10 core, and I have a field called PolicyReference with an IDX_PolicyReference index, and I am trying to set up an exact search on this field

So I execute a query like the following:

```
IDX_PolicyReference:ABC123
```

This has been working fine for years.

Now devs are sending PolicyReference values that contain a space: for example

```
IDX_PolicyReference:AB 123
```

This does not return the exact search result I am expecting.

From reading other questions on SO regarding this, it sounds like I need to turn off stemming.

I can successfully find the PolicyReference if I put double quotes around the value

```
IDX_PolicyReference:"AB 123"
```

But I'm trying to solve this without having to change the app that calls SOLR.

The schema.xml has the following elements in it.

```
<field name="PolicyReference" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<copyField source="PolicyReference" dest="IDX_PolicyReference"/>
<field name="IDX_PolicyReference" type="text_Exact" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

<fieldType name="text_Exact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My understanding was that when using KeywordTokenizerFactory, it takes the search term as one keyword. But it seems like space breaks it.

Is there another tokenizerfactory that I can use to achieve what I'm trying? Are there other attributes I can apply to the tokenizer xml element, or a filter that I can add that will turn off the stemming for this field - something that I can change in schema.xml and reindex that will allow my search request to work as is?

Again, I'm trying to avoid changing the app that calls SOLR.

Comment: The problem is that the query is being parsed by the query parser _before_ it hits the field definitions. In effect your query is parsed as `IDX_PolicyReference:AB <default search field>:123`. The KeywordTokenizer will generate neither of those tokens, and changing the tokenizer will end up creating hits for something like `AB FOO 123` (since both `AB` and `123` is present). The correct way of handling this would be to escape the space - i.e. make sure Solr sees `IDX_PolicyReference:AB\ 123` instead. Which appcontainer are you using with 4.10? It might be able to rewrite the query for you.

Comment: Makes more sense to me now, @MatsLindh - thanks! I'm going to change my app to escape the spaces as you suggested